# How can I make my recursive C program more efficient?

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, recursion, malloc

I have to write a program in c that finds the number of pairs which verify this condition:

```
i<j && a[i]>a[j]
```

a[] is an array which contains N elements

example: given **N=4** and **a={1,7,2,0}** the numbers of pairs is **4** : **(1,0), (7,2), (7,0), (2,0)**

I wrote this code that works, but it is very inefficient:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 4

int count(int a[],int i, int j);

int main(){

   int i,c=0;

   int a[]={1,7,2,0};

   for(i=0; i<N-1;i++)
      c+=count(a,i,N-1);

   printf("%d",c);

   return 0;
}

int count(int a[N], int i, int j){
    if(j<0)
       return 0;

     if(i<j && a[i]>a[j])
        return 1+count(a,i,j-1);

     return 0+count(a,i,j-1);
}
```

also, how do I implement the dynamic generation of the array using malloc? should I create the array in the main function of in the count function?

Comment: First, I don't see where you are printing out any pairs.  I am missing something?  Why do you think this is not efficient?  Allocating memory on the stack is very efficient - just decrementing a stack pointer.

Comment: Is there a constraint that you must use a function? A recursive function? The most straight-forward approach uses two loops around the condition you are checking (and could be written inline in `main()` or in a simple, non-recursive function). Allocate the array in `main()` — not in `count()`. `int *b = malloc(200 * sizeof(*b)); if (b != 0) { for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) b[j] = rand(); ...now check for decreasing pairs... }`.

Comment: yes, I have to use a recursive function; also I just need to print out the number of pairs, not the pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to count inversions in an array. This can be achieved using a tehnique simillar with the merge sort algorithm. I suggest you take a look at the following paper: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2013/cmsc451/Lects/lect09.pdf.

Speaking about dynamic array generation, you may want to know that since C99, there are [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (their size does not need to be a constant anymore).

If you really want or need to use malloc, you should take a look at pointers first. After you know how to handle pointers, everything will be clear, because malloc just sets a playground for you to be able to play with pointers.

Comment: thanks! you were right, I needed to look at the problem in a different way; the program which counts the number of inversions in an array has the complexity O(n*logn) which is equal to mergesort complexity http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/   now i just need to find a way to create the array dynamically

Comment: Interesting. The code at geeksforgeeks.org leaks like a sieve, but that's easily fixed. I measured and timed the two variants of the code, and for arrays up to about 150, the simpler quadratic code outperforms the more complex merge-sort code. However, the O(N*N) behaviour soon costs dramatically more than the O(N log N) behaviour of the merge sort code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to use recursion or how it could make it faster. I would suggest a double for loop since it is easier to read:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < N-1 ; i++)
    for(j = i+1 ; j < N ; j++)
        c += (a[i]>a[j]) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I know the double loop is easier... the teacher gave us this exercise and told us to solve it using recursive functions, also he mentioned something about mergesort, but I don't see how I can apply it here

Comment: Oké, then ignore my answer :). Haven't used recursion or mergesort in a while, so not going to try answering it without testing it first.

Answer (score 0):

In general your recursive solution has continuations after the recursion in them (the addition). You can make it a tad better by using an accumulator as one argument to create the return value and for some compilers the recursion will be optimized into a loop:

```
int count(int a[N], int i, int j)
{
    return count_aux(a, i, j, 0);
}

int count_aux(int a[N], int i, int j, int acc)
{
    if ( j<0 )
       return acc;
    else
       return count_aux(a,i,j-1, ( i<j && a[i] > a[j] ? acc+1 : acc ));
}
```